# Remove uninstalled apps from application menu

Tags: appcenter, applications, slingshot

I just did a fresh install of Elementary OS 6 Odin and I installed apps that I need and uninstalled these I don't need, so I uninstalled Epiphany and Camera app from AppCenter. After few hours I realised I still have these apps in Application Menu...
I tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`, I also tried `sudo apt-get remove epiphany-browser`. It doesn't work. I don't have these apps in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. When I try to uninstall them using Application Menu I get the popup saying
`Program status is not set as Installed in AppCenter for package: Web Browser for GNOME`. Anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the menulibre to do this: `sudo apt install menulibre`

Answer (score 0):

Elementary has moved to a new app format - Flatpak. This means that apt commands won't work. To view all Flatpak apps, use `flatpak list`. To uninstall an app, use `flatpak uninstall [app name]`. For example `flatpak uninstall org.gnome.Epiphany` should uninstall Epiphany/Web browser and `flatpak uninstall io.elementary.camera` should remove the Camera app.